# Object Required Error with JSON to VBA converting Process

Tags: json, vba, excel

I got an error message

> Run-Time '424' Object Required

when I click to debug it highlights this section to me `For Each Value In Parsed("model")`

Code is like below;

```
Sub Test1()

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Dim JsonText As String
Dim Parsed As Scripting.Dictionary

' Read .json file
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("\exampleJSON.json", ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close

' Parse json to Dictionary
' "values" is parsed as Collection
' each item in "values" is parsed as Dictionary
Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)

' Prepare and write values to sheet
Dim Values As Variant
ReDim Values(Parsed("model").Count, 3)

Dim Value As Dictionary
Dim i As Long

i = 0
For Each Value In Parsed("model")
  Values(i, 0) = Value("name")
  Values(i, 1) = Value("type")
  Values(i, 2) = Value("window")
  i = i + 1
Next Value

Sheets("TEST_SHEET").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Parsed("model").Count, 3)) = Values

End Sub
```

And the JSON file is like that:

```
{"model": {
    "name": "Hakan",
    "type": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

What's the problem caused do you have any idea why there's not any object seen in VBA?

Comment: Try `ReDim Preserve`, just doing `ReDim` will wipe out all of the existing data in the array.

Comment: @BrownishMonster now it gives an error at "ReDim Preserve" row. Error is type mismatch.

Comment: Try `Dim Values() As Variant`, or something to that effect.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, but your approach seems off. 
 `Parsed("model")` is a Scripting Dictionary with five keys "Name", "type" "window", "image" and "text".  When you iterate over `Parsed("model")` you're iterating over those keys (as strings).

Comment: @TimWilliams, in fact, I tried to implement an example from this page: [(https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)] but I didn't succeed

Comment: No-one can help you without knowing exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below example to convert each `model` property into row of the table, and output the result to worksheet. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    ' Read JSON
    sJSONString = ReadTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\source.json", -2)
    ' Parse JSON
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then MsgBox "Invalid JSON": Exit Sub
    ' Output "model" to the worksheet
    JSON.ToArray vJSON("model"), aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .Rows.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Function ReadTextFile(sPath, lFormat)
    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

The output for the sample you provided is as follows:

[image: output]

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way, but using a regex to parse some Json is inefficient and the way you implemented it is unreliable. Try to parse this one for instance: https://catalog.archives.gov/api/v1 . If you wish to use a regex, first tokenize with a single pattern `[\{\}\[\],:]|""(?:\\""|[^""])*""|[^\s\[\]\{\},:]+` and then parse each token recursively.